# Java more elegant way to write if statements with images

Tags: java, image, short

Is there a more elegant/shorter/organized way of writing this bit of code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < SCREENSIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SCREENSIZE; j++) {
            if (map[y + i][x + j] == '@')
                g.drawImage(item, j * TILESIZE,i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == ' ')
                g.drawImage(ground, j * TILESIZE,i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == 'i')
                g.drawImage(bush, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '~')
                g.drawImage(ocean, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '=')
                g.drawImage(fence, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '#')
                g.drawImage(grass, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == 'Y')
                g.drawImage(townsPerson, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '/')
                g.drawImage(house01, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '¯')
                g.drawImage(house02, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '\\')
                g.drawImage(house03, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '[')
                g.drawImage(house04, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == 'n')
                g.drawImage(house05, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '_')
                g.drawImage(house06, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == ']')
                g.drawImage(house07, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '`')
                g.drawImage(cground, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == 'O')
                g.drawImage(boulder, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == 'Ÿ')
                g.drawImage(alien, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == '.')
                g.drawImage(tree01, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
            else if (map[y + i][x + j] == 'T')
                g.drawImage(tree02, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Map<Char,Image> tiles;`, add all of those to the map `.put('O', boulder)`, use the mapping as lookup table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere (in the constructor?), save a `Map` as a member variable:

```
images = new HashMap<Character, Image>();
images.put('@', item);
images.put(' ', ground);
```

Then, your drawing will look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SCREENSIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SCREENSIZE; j++) {
        g.drawImage(images.get(map[y+i][x+j]), j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried putting the code in my compiler and declared my HashMap like so: `HashMap images;`. It gives me warnings at declaration and when using `images.put`. Also I get an error when using `images = new HashMap<char, Image>();` it says dimensions expected after this token (char is underlined)?

Comment: Declare it parameterized like so: `HashMap<Char, Image>` .  You also have to use `Char` with a capital 'c' because of Java's *interesting* type system and what it allows you to use as template parameters.

Comment: Sorry, it's `Character` not `Char`.

Answer (score 5):

The first improvement could be to use a switch/case structure, but in your case, a simple map (`Map<Char,Image>`) will be even better.

Going even further, you could use an enum instead of characters to identify the objects, which will help you avoid typos, but at the very least you should be using character constants, like

```
public static final char MAP_ITEM = '@';
public static final char MAP_GROUND = ' ';
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're basing off a character, you can use a `switch` statement.
The other thing you can do is, since you're using `g.drawImage(SOMETHING, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null)` in every case, you can extract everything that's the same to after the switch and just assign some variable and use that for what changes

EX:

```
Object graphic;
switch (map[y + i][x + j]) {
case '@': 
    graphic = item;
    break;
case '#':
    graphic = grass;
    break;
// etc....
}
g.drawImage(graphic, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a switch/case (not a map) because the compiler would have more room to optimize since it knows the exact set of char values you are switching on:

```
...
switch(map[y+i][x+j]) {
    case: '@': image = item; break;
    case: ' ': image = ground; break;
    ...
}
g.drawImage(image, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
...
```

Comment: ALSO: the fastest solution is if you are sure you will never get a value other than those you are testing then you can create an **array** of size 255, assign tiles like `tile_array['@'] = item;`, and then replace all of your code with a **single** line: `g.drawImage(tile_array[map[y+i][x+j]], j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch with a char value so that might be clearer. Also the 2nd, 3rd and forth parameters are always the same so maybe set a var in the switch and call the method outside. A little pseudo code:

```
for() {
  for() {
     Image obj;
     switch (map[y+i][x +j]) {
       case '@':
         Obj = item;
         break;
     // other cases
       default:
       //default or error handling
   }
   g.drawImage(obj, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, null);
 }
}
```